# Функция создает новое окно. В нем мне нужно ввести значение и выполнить другую функцию

Tags: python, tkinter

Часть кода

```js
def button5_command():
    data_window = Tk()
   
    data_window.geometry("600x120")


    time_step_text = Label(data_window, text="Введите шаг времени")
    time_step_text.pack()
    global ent
    entry_time_step = Entry(data_window, width=25)
    entry_time_step.pack()

    button = Button(data_window, text="Ввести шаг времени", command=button5_sup_command)
    button.pack()


def button5_sup_command():
    print(entry_time_step.get())
```

```js
Ошибка: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\OOP\Расчетное задание\model_shop.py", line 198, in button5_sup_command
    print(entry_time_step.get())
NameError: name 'entry_time_step' is not defined
```

Comment: Дочерние окна в ткинтер должны создаваться с помощью `Toplevel`, основное окно `Tk` одно на все приложение, как правило, и к нему привязан основной цикл. Судя по названию папки OOP вам надо его применить, чтоб не создавать глобальных переменных из виджетов используемых в разных функциях.

Comment: У меня там действительно используется главное окно. Если вкратце, то у меня есть основное окно с кнопками. Нажимая на 5 кнопку, выполняется функция button5_command (тут появится новое окно data_window). Мне в ней нужно ввести фаг времени. Далее функция button5_sup_command должна выводить таблицу. Я не понимаю, почему не передается переменная entry_time_step. Я сделал тестовый код, где новое окно открывается не в функции, всё работает.

Comment: Проблему решил. Сделал переменную entry_time_step глобальной